# I'm looking for an animated TV show about a normal blonde guy but alien suddenly show up

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I don't remember the plot. I saw the trailer on Amazon and you may ask, "Why not look at Amazon?". I tried but it was foreign show and I keep bumping into anime.

The comic was about a normal blonde guy who kept fighting in the street. I forget his name which is the title of the comic. His life changed when some alien entities showed up secretly and he has to fight them off.

Edit: this comic is from Europe and I think it came from the early 2000s

Comment: What did the aliens look like?  That might narrow it down.

Comment: As for the alien i don't know what it look like think of it like the birdbox but the sight of them won't make you kill yourself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Lastman](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lastman_(comic_book))

> In the "Valley of Kings", a world where magic is acknowledged as reality, an annual grand tournament sponsored by the King and Queen is being prepared. Young Adrian Velba works all year in the combat school of Master Jansen to participate. Sadly, Adrian's partner suddenly falls ill and deserts. Since it is a duo tournament, the young boy is forced to give up his dream... until Richard Aldana, a hunk with bearish manners comes out of nowhere to unexpectedly ally himself with Adrian.

I was mistaken about it being from Amazon.

One episode is free on YouTube:

Comment: "Video unavailable" Can you link to some video that's not region restricted?

Comment: You could used norvpn but other cartoon websites could work